# Only the geodesic distance matters for maximally symmetric spacetimes

Tags: anti-de-sitter-spacetime

*Any physical quantity $K(t,x,x')$ on a maximally symmetric spacetime only depends on the geodesic distance between the points $x$ and $x'$.*

Why is this so?

**N.B.:**

This statement is different from the statement that

*The geodesic distance on any spacetime is invariant under an arbitrary coordinate transformation of that spacetime.*

Comment: This statement is incorrect, geodesic distance is invariant under every coordinate transform in every space-time. Perhaps you should check and cite the source for more context.

Comment: see my edit to question!

Comment: [Crossposted on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2562388/289977) and [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/288287/106114).

Comment: @void: I don't think that's quite right; geodesic distance isn't invariant under diffeomorphisms, but only under isometries; I assume that isometries is what the OP is talking about.

Comment: @MoziburUllah So you are really telling me that the notion of geodesic distance is dependent on the coordinate system in which you compute it?

Comment: @void: not at all; I'm saying that diffeomorphisms are transformations of the manifold that don't take into account geodesic distance, in other words they ignore the euclidean structure on a manifold; whereas isometries do - thats why they preserve distance; its only being more precise with language.

Comment: @MoziburUllah In relativity, geodesic distance is the extremal length of curves connecting the two points measured by the pseudo-Riemannian metric, not any Euclidean notion of distance. This length is diffeomorphism invariant. See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity#Deriving_the_geodesic_equation_via_an_action).

Comment: @void: can you point out where the wiki makes this claim - I don't see it? If they do make this claim then they're wrong. A smooth manifold need not have any riemannian structure, and so no distances can be defined; yet it still has diffeomorphisms. perhaps you're conflating diffeomorphisms with isometries? An isometry is after all a diffeomorphism (the reverse does not hold).